# Neo4j: Error: unexpected symbol in "LOAD CSV" in R markdown

Tags: r, neo4j, cypher, r-neo4j

I was reading [importing CSV Data into Neo4j][1] and I tried to execute

```
library("RNeo4j")
library("curl")

graph <- startGraph("http://localhost:7474/db/data", username = "neo4j", password = "")
clear(graph, input = F)

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///data//airlines.csv" AS row
CREATE (n:airlines)
SET n = row,
  n.carrier = toFloat(row.carrier),
  n.name = toFloat(row.name)
```

I got the following error message:

```
> > LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///data//airlines.csv" AS row
Error: unexpected symbol in "LOAD CSV"
> CREATE (n:airlines)
Error: could not find function "CREATE"
> SET n = row,
Error: unexpected symbol in "SET n"
>   n.carrier = toFloat(row.carrier),
Error: unexpected ',' in "  n.carrier = toFloat(row.carrier),"
>   n.name = toFloat(row.name)
Error: could not find function "toFloat"
>
```

Comment: Share the full statement you used please, not just a portion.

Comment: @LendaLD please add more details. The tags suggest that you are using Neo4j from R. How do you pass the Cypher commands to Neo4j?

Comment: @MichaelHunger @GáborSzárnyas thanks for the kind suggestion, I'm actually not sure how to pass the cypher commands to Neo4j, and I just followed the official guide and put `LOAD CSV` directly in my code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get familiar with the RNeo4j package, you should check the README in the [RNeo4j GitHub repository](https://github.com/nicolewhite/RNeo4j) and the 
[reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RNeo4j/RNeo4j.pdf).

You should put your query in a multiline string and use the `cypher` function. Note that I changed the quotes to apostrophes (`'`) in the Cypher query.

I also removed the import for the `curl` library as `RNeo4j` imports it transitively.

```
library("RNeo4j")

graph = startGraph("http://localhost:7474/db/data", username = "neo4j", password = "")
clear(graph, input = F)

query = "
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///data//airlines.csv' AS row
CREATE (n:airlines)
SET n = row,
  n.carrier = toFloat(row.carrier),
  n.name = toFloat(row.name)
"
cypher(graph, query)
```

Make sure that you provide an absolute path to the CSV file as shown in the [Neo4j CSV Import Guide](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/).